# Show Copied Tooltip When Successfully Copied Through Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, html, copy

First of all I am a beginner in javascript/HTML and successfully created a copy function where the value of

tag is copied on button press.

Here is the code so far:

Javascript:

```
<script>
    var copyEmailBtn = document.querySelector('.emoji-copy-button');  
  copyEmailBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {  
    // Select the email link anchor text  
    var emailLink = document.querySelector('.emoji-copy');  
    var range = document.createRange();  
    range.selectNode(emailLink);  
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);  
  
    try {  
      // Now that we've selected the anchor text, execute the copy command  
      var successful = document.execCommand('copy');  
      var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';  
      console.log('Copy email command was ' + msg);  
    } catch(err) {  
      console.log('Oops, unable to copy');  
    }  
  
    // Remove the selections - NOTE: Should use
    // removeRange(range) when it is supported  
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();  
  });
  </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="copy-emoji-section">
<p class="emoji-copy-text" id="">Copy Emoji</p>
<p class="emoji-copy" id="emoji_copy"></p>
<button class="emoji-copy-button" id="emoji_copy_button">Copy Emoji</button>
</div>
```

The copy functions works fine but, I want to show a tooltip below that text field that the content has been copied. I cannot figure how to make it work

help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your tooltip HTML inside parent div like this -

```
<div class="copy-emoji-section">
  <div>
    <p class="emoji-copy-text" id="">Copy Emoji</p>
    <p class="emoji-copy" id="emoji_copy"></p>
    <button class="emoji-copy-button" id="emoji_copy_button">Copy Emoji</button>
  </div>
  <div class="your-tooltip">...</div>
</div>
```

style

```
.copy-emoji-section {
  position: relative;
}

.your-tooltip {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  transition: all .3s;
}
 
.your-tooltip.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

And in your js, you need to attach the .show class to .your-tooltip html like this:

```
    var copyEmailBtn = document.querySelector('.emoji-copy-button');
    var yourToolTip = document.querySelector('.your-tooltip');

    copyEmailBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {  
      // Select the email link anchor text  
      var emailLink = document.querySelector('.emoji-copy');  
      var range = document.createRange();  
      range.selectNode(emailLink);  
      window.getSelection().addRange(range);  
  
      try {  
        // Now that we've selected the anchor text, execute the copy command  
        var successful = document.execCommand('copy');  
        var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';

        // Add the .show class when successful.
        if(successful){
          yourToolTip.classList.add('.show');
        }
    
        console.log('Copy email command was ' + msg);  
      } catch(err) {  
        console.log('Oops, unable to copy');  
      }  
  
      // Remove the selections - NOTE: Should use
      // removeRange(range) when it is supported  
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();  
  });
```